# My web fonts look pixelated, especially the vertical parts of 'l's 'i's and 't's

Tags: wordpress, fonts

[image: Messed up fonts]

All WordPress sites render strangely and Google searches look weird as well.

For WordPress sites, it loads fine, but then looks like the picture moments later.

Additional information:

1. Mozilla Firefox had the same issue on the same page.
2. Enabling Microsoft TrueFont did nothing.
3. Restarting chrome did nothing (except the last time).
4. If you use an extension (font changer) to force all fonts into 'Times New Roman,' the problem vanishes.
5. Chrome LCD Text Antialiasing does not fix the problem.
6. Forcing other sites to use 'Noto Sans' (pre-relaunch) replicated the problem.
7. Whatever font Google used was also messed up. After relaunching and installing 'Noto Sans,' google was fixed. Google's font does **not** appear to be 'Noto Sans,' however, which leads me to believe it fixed itself somehow.
8. The problem appears in incognito mode.
9. Clearing the cache does not fix the problem.

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question. "All sites are screwed over" is not a solvable problem. If this is a particular website or font, it looks like the font might miss hinting information.

Comment: [Read Please](http://imgur.com/LHOJeJY)
Please quote correctly if at all.

Comment: This sounds like a browser problem, and not a programming problem, and if so it is not on-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the font in question, which I discovered to be 'Noto Sans,' to my computer. Following a relaunch of chrome, it seemed to fix itself.

EDIT: This did not fix the problem, I had to manually install an extension to replace the text on pages with a custom font before the problem vanished.